# how take the value in textangular editor in ng-repat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i use textangular editor which is in ng-repeat.

### in html

```
  <ul ng-repeat="lecture in section.lectures">
        <div class="col-md-12 article-show"  >
       <form ng-submit="lecture_content('article',$index+1,lecture.id)" style="width:100%;">
          <div text-angular id="lecture_text{{lecture.id}}" ng-model="htmlVariable[lecture.id]" style="width:100%;" ></div>
        <button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#stext"  class="sub-sub-section-add">Submit</button>
        </form>
   </div>
 </ul>
```

### in controller

```
     $scope.lecture_content=function(type,value,x)
{

    if(type=='article')
    {
        console.log($scope.htmlVariable[lecture.id]);
       lecture_description=document.getElementById('lecture_text'+x).value;


    }
```

i think the problem is on controller part. how can i access value in text editor? thanks in advance.

Comment: The directive uses double binding for the `ng-model`. So you get the text in your variable that you put in. In your case, `ng-model="htmlVariable[lecture.id]"`. So your text will be in `htmlVariable[lecture.id]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.lecture_content=function(type,value,x) 
{
    if (type == 'article')
    {
        var x = this.htmlVariable[id];
    }
```